# How do I exclude multiple XML nodes in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to transform an XML document into HTML using XSLT.

The document is external and not fully documented. To that end, I only know (and therefore handle) some of the nodes.

New nodes may be added.

I want first determine if there are any unknown child nodes and if so, display them simply in an HTML table. Nothing fancy.

My current xslt snippet is ...

```
<xsl:if test="*[not(service or searchtext or clientreference or threshold or resultcount or results or options or error)]">
<div class="requestSupportData">
    <table class="zebra">
        <caption>Request supportive data</caption>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Element</th>
                <th>Value</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="2">
                    <a href="#top">Top</a>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>
            <xsl:for-each select="*[not(service or searchtext or clientreference or threshold or resultcount or results or options or error)]">
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        <xsl:value-of select="local-name(.)"/>
                    </th>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

What I'm trying to achieve here is are there any nodes NOT called service, searchtext, etc. and of so, render them as a simple name/value pair in an HTML table.

I'm either getting nothing or everything, including the unwanted elements.

Regards,

Richard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This expression:

```
 *[not(service or searchtext or clientreference or ...)]
```

means "all child elements that have no *child elements* named `<service>`, `<searchtext>`, etc." Change it to

```
 *[not(self::service or self::searchtext or self::clientreference or ...)]
```

which means "all child elements that *are not* named `<service>`, `<searchtext>`, etc."